# Example of non associative floating point addition

Tags: floating-point

I'm writing an article about floating numbers. I put inside some simple test to try in Javascript console.

I'm looking for an example of non commutative addition ie: (x+y)+z!=(z+x)+y

If you have some values for x y z that works thank you.

Comment: Why are you writing an article about this if you don't even know how to construct an example yourself?

Comment: Why are you writing an article about this and offering your readers an example which involves both commutativity and associativity ?

Comment: EOF : I'm on my phone right now and thought it would be a good reference to have it there too. I'll found an example as soon as I get a pc. What is the point in your comment? What positive thing does it bring to the website? Does it makes you feel better to be rude like that?

Comment: @bokan I like to make the world a better place. One means to that end is preventing the creation of *even more* bad articles/blogs written by people who don't understand the subject they write about.

Comment: Floating-point addition *is* commutative; it's associativity that doesn't hold.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such example, because floating point addition, as defined by IEEE-754, is *guaranteed* to be commutative. The relevant verbiage:

> ...Each of the operations shall be performed as if it first produced an intermediate result correct to infinite precision and with unbounded range, and then coerced this intermediate result to fit in the destination's format.

That is, the addition itself is performed with infinite precision; all errors in the result come from the need to discard some of that precision. Since infinite-precision (that is, "regular") addition is commutative, that means the operation as a whole is commutative.

What you may be thinking of is associativity. Floating point addition is not associative, because the precision loss following adding the first two numbers will not generally be the same as that from adding the last two numbers. The most common example of this is known as "catastrophic cancellation": `(1 + 1e100) + -1e100 = 0`, and `1 + (1e100 + -1e100) = 1`.

Answer (score -3):

It's quite easy, it does that most of the time when we use floating point which are not exact representation of decimal values (most of them).

ie :

this could be typed in javascript console (F12) and return false

```
var x=0.1; var y=0.3; var z=0.00001; (x+y)+z==(z+x)+y
```

Comment: That's showing non-associativity, not non-commutativity.