# Are there non-negative floating points a,b,c such that a + (b - a) * c > b with a < b and c < 1?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

This question is related to [When does (b - a) + a != b exactly in floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51376227/when-does-b-a-a-b-exactly-in-floating-point) but with an additional multiplicator `c` that must be strictly smaller than `1`.

Formally I am asking myself if there exist any floating point numbers `a`, `b`, and `c` such that

1. `0 <= a < b`
2. `0 <= c < 1`
3. `a + (b - a) * c > b`.

If there exists such a triple I am further wondering if we can find normal floating point numbers or if some of the three need to be subnormal.

First of all to find such a triple it is pretty clear that if it works it will work with `c = 1. - epsilon`, i.e. the largest floating point smaller than `1`. So to find suiting values for `a` and `b` I tried multiple things without success:

1. Generate a lot of random values
2. Generate pairs `a = i / n` and `b = j / n` with `0 <= i < j <= n` as suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51383057/23137796. I tried for all `(i,j,n)` pairs with `n <= 1000`. I could find many pairs with `a + (b - a) > b` but none with `a + (b - a) * c > b`.
3. I tried to generate `a` and `b` values that are close to each other (i.e. only epsilon away from each other or some constant multiple of epsilon away, up to 100). I couldn't find any pair that satisfies `a + (b - a) > b`.

Edit: Thank you for everyone presenting examples with rounding mode towards infinity, I can see that with this rounding mode we can find examples. I am mostly interested in rounding mode "Round to nearest, ties to even" that is used in many programming languages by default, should have mentioned this to begin with.

Comment: Trivial example if `b-a` is infinity and `c>0` (possible for very large `b` and `a=-b`).

Comment: @chtz good call, although it is not the interesting case I am interested in, let me constrain the problem to `a >= 0` :P.

Comment: why did you remove the bullet-point about a,b,c not being infinity or NaN? Maybe you think its obvious that those are not interesting but those are the first things people check when asked if floating-point-expressions can yield weird results

Comment: Next case you may rule out, if you set the rounding mode to towards infinity, you will have lots of cases ...

Comment: @chtz yes I think I am mostly interested in binary64 or binary32 with rounding mode "Round to nearest, ties to even"

Answer (score 3):

### Summary

There are such numbers when rounding toward +∞ is used. There are not such numbers when rounding to nearest with ties to even is used in a binary floating-point format. There are such numbers in non-binary formats.

In this answer, text in `code font` represents floating-point arithmetic. Text not in code font represents real-number arithmetic.

### Rounding Toward +∞

Consider IEEE-754 binary32 with rounding toward +∞. Let `a` be ½−2<sup>−25</sup>, the representable number just below ½. Let `b` be 1. Let `c` be 1−2<sup>−24</sup>, the representable number just below 1. `b`−`a` (mathematical subtraction) is ½+2<sup>−25</sup>. That is not representable, so `b-a` (floating-point subtraction) with rounding toward +∞ produces ½+2<sup>−24</sup>. `b-a`•`c` is ½+2<sup>−24</sup>−2<sup>−25</sup>-2<sup>−48</sup>, so `(b-a)*c` produces ½+2<sup>−24</sup>. Then `a`+`(b-a)*c` is ½−2<sup>−25</sup>+½+2<sup>−24</sup> = 1−2<sup>25</sup>+2<sup>−24</sup> = 1+2<sup>−25</sup>. 1+2<sup>−25</sup> is not representable, so rounding toward +∞ produces 1+2<sup>−23</sup>,  so `a + (b-a)*c` produces 1+2<sup>−23</sup>, which is greater than `b`.

Demonstrating in C, the output of:

```
#include <fenv.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON


int main(void)
{
    fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
    float a = nexttowardf(.5f, 0);
    float b = 1;
    float c = nexttowardf(1, 0);
    printf("%a\n", a + (b-a)*c);
}
```

is:

```
0x1.000002p+0
```

### Round to Nearest With Binary Floating-Point

This is not possible in a binary format with round-to-nearest-ties-to-even. Proof:

Consider, that, if `a + (b-a)*c` is greater than `b`, it is at least one ULP of `b` greater than `b`. Let *u* be the ULP of `b`. Consider first `a + (b-a)`. Since `a` < `b`, `b-a` ≤ `b`, so the ULP of `b-a` is at most the UP of `b`, *u*. With round-to-nearest, the maximum error in a single operation is ½ ULP, for the ULP of the result. There are values for `a` and `b` where `b-a` rounds up by ½ ULP, such as when we subtract 1½•2<sup>−23</sup> from 2−2<sup>−23</sup>. (2−2<sup>−23</sup> − 1½•2<sup>−23</sup> = 2 − 2½•2<sup>−23</sup>, which rounds up to 2 − 2•2<sup>−23</sup>.)

So, for `b-a`, it is possible to produce a result of `b` − `a` + ½ *u*.

Then when we add `a`, there are again values for which the addition in `a + (b-a)` rounds up by ½ ULP. We know from above the mathematical result is at most `a` + `b` − `a` + ½*u* = `b` + ½*u*. This is halfway to the next representable number after `b`, so it will, with round-to-nearest-ties-to-even, round up if the next representable number has an even low digit in its significand. The numbers above are an example of that; with `a` = 1½•2<sup>−23</sup> and `b` = 2−2<sup>−23</sup>, `a + (b-a)` yields 2, which is greater than `b`.

Observe that we just barely achieved this. The final addition rounded up because there was exactly ½*u* rounding error in `b-a`, the maximum possible. It is not possible to arrange for the result of `a + (b-a)` to be any greater than `b` + ½*u*. So, when we consider `a + (b-a)*c`, we must not lose any of this achieved rounding error. The result of `(b-a)*c` must be `b-a` and not any less, or `a + (b-a)*c` will be lower than the value needed to allow rounding up.

The greatest `c` can be is the next representable number less than 1. The above examples use binary32, but we will consider binary formats generally, so the greatest `c` is 1−2<sup>−*p*</sup>, where *p* is the precision of the format (the number of digits in the significand).

`b-a`•`c` is necessarily less than `b-a`, so we want `(b-a)*c` to round up to compensate for that. Suppose `b-a` has the largest significand in a binary format, 2−2<sup>1−*p*</sup> (using [1, 2) for the normal significand interval). `c` also has this significand. (It is  1−2<sup>−*p*</sup>, which normalizes to 2−2<sup>1−*p*</sup>.) Then product of the significands in `b-a`•`c` is (2−2<sup>1−*p*</sup>)<sup>2</sup> = 4 − 2•2<sup>1−*p*</sup> + (2<sup>1−*p*</sup>)<sup>2</sup> = 4 − 2<sup>2−*p*</sup> + 2<sup>2−2*p*</sup>. Scaling that to the normal interval yields 2 − 2<sup>1−*p*</sup> + 2<sup>1−2*p*</sup>.

2 − 2<sup>1−*p*</sup> is the largest significand, and its ULP is 2<sup>1−*p*</sup>, so the product does not exceed the largest significand by at least ½ ULP unless  2<sup>1−2*p*</sup> ≥ ½•2<sup>1−*p*</sup>, implying p ≤ 1. (I will leave it to the reader to consider whether there is a solution with *p* = 1 and what to replace round-to-nearest-ties-to-even with when all significands of nonzero numbers have an odd low digit.)

Therefore the product of this largest possible significand of `a-b` with `c` cannot round up, and no lower significand can round up either. Therefore, we cannot achieve the necessary rounding error to make `a + (b-a)*c` exceed `b`.

### Bonus

For the *p* = 1 case left to the reader above, the representable numbers are … ¼, ½, 1, 2, 4,… The largest possible value for `c` is ½. We can consider any representable number for `b`, as there is only one significand (1) for non-zero numbers, and all behaviors will scale as the exponent is changed. Let’s choose `b` = 4, which makes `a` at most 2. For `b-a`, the result for any `a` is at most `b`, so let’s replace `a + (b-a)*c` with `a + b*c`. This is `a + 4*½`, so `a + 2`. Since `a` ≤ 2, `a + 2` ≤ 4. So there is no solution in this degenerate floating-point format.

### Decimal Format

Consider a two-digit decimal format with round-to-nearest. Let `a` be 15, `b` be 130, and `c` be .99. Then `b`-`a` = 115, so `b-a` rounds to 120, and `b-a`•`c` = 118.8, so `(b-a)*c` rounds to 120. Then `a` + `(b-a)*c` = 15 + 120 = 135, so `a + (b-a)*c` rounds to 140, and 140 is greater than `b`.

Comment: Nice, example thank you so much! As I mentioned in my example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78113445/are-there-non-negative-floating-points-a-b-c-such-that-a-b-a-c-b-with/78115101#comment137712337_78113445) I am mostly interested in rounding mode "Round to nearest, ties to even", can we modify your example for this case too? I will modify my question to add this.

Comment: Thank you for providing such a detailed proof! I cannot fully follow the part that argues that `b-a`•`c` does not round up, are you arguing that if we multiply any positive floating point with `c` we will never round up?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, in binary floating-point with round-to-nearest, multiplying by 1−1^−p never rounds up in magnitude (away from zero). In decimal floating-point it can. E.g., with two-digit decimal, 11•.99 = 10.89, which rounds to 11.

Comment: @Ben: I added a decimal example. With two-digit decimal using round-to-nearest-ties-to-even, `15 + (130-15)*.99` produces 140, which exceeds 130.