# Are floating point numbers really commutative?

Tags: point, addition, floating, associative

It's said that floating point addition is commutative but not associative.

An example of it being non associative is the following:

`(1 + 1e100) + -1e100 = 0`, and `1 + (1e100 + -1e100) = 1`

But doesn't this also prove that they are not commutative by the following:

`1 + 1e100 + -1e100 = 0`, and `1e100 + -1e100 + 1 = 1`

Comment: When you says "It's said", where did you see that?

Comment: @leleogere It's mentioned on wikipedia and all over stackoverflow.

Eg this answer mentions it's guaranteed to be commutative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46776601/3901677

Comment: That's good to know! I think that the problem in you second example is associativity, not commutativity. If I'm not wrong, python computes additions from the left to the right, meaning that in the first computation, it will compute `1 + 1e100` (`=1e100`), and then subtract  `1e100`, which gives `0`. In the second example, it starts by computing `1e100 - 1e100` (`=0`), and then add `1`, which gives `1`. This is an associativity problem due to the order the operations are made by python, not a commutativity problem.